# Whenever I try to run Chrome using selenium using Python I get this error

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, nft

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\BABA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1921, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\BABA\Downloads\Compressed\NFTs-Upload-to-OpenSea-main\NFTs-Upload-to-OpenSea-main\openseaupload.py", line 111, in main_program_loop
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(
  File "C:\Users\BABA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 76, in __init__
    RemoteWebDriver.__init__(
  File "C:\Users\BABA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "C:\Users\BABA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "C:\Users\BABA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\BABA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot connect to chrome at localhost:8989
from session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 96
Current browser version is 98.0.4758.102
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: first format error message, and describe problem inside question, not in title. And finally show code which gives this error. At this moment we can only downvote or close this question.

Comment: error explains everything - you have browser `98` but your chromedriver can work only with `96` - so simply you have to download and install newer `ChromeDriver` - see: https://chromedriver.chromium.org/. Usually when you update browser then you have to also update driver.

Answer (score 0):

Install latest version of chrome driver from [Chromedriver](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads) or match the current version of chrome installed in your PC

Answer (score 0):

This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 96
Current browser version is 98.0.4758.102

need to download correct ChromeDriver version for your browser.